# What is the correct way to add a Date Filter to a scripted search (SuiteScript 1.0)?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a script built search in SS1.0 that includes a date range filter, however some transactions continue to be included despite their `{trandate}` being outside the given range.

I have tried both adding filter objects, and using a filter Expression.

Currently it looks like:

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('trandate',null,'onorafter',startdate));
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('trandate',null,'onorbefore',statementdate));
```

Which should result in retrieving transactions between start date and statementdate *inclusive*.

Yet, still get results outside the range (ie, before the startdate)

Comment: please ensure that you have start date and end date then use within

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('trandate',null,'within',startdate,statementdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of those should work. If you have a real dates though make sure you convert them:

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('trandate',null,'onorafter',nlapiDateToString(startdate)));
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('trandate',null,'onorbefore',nlapiDateToString(statementdate)));
```

Comment: Weirdly I have worked in a one world account where the dates had to be formatted YYYY-MM-DD.  Unless I am getting a date from a Netsuite date field I almost always do the conversion.